# mysql: how to return a NULL result when no records found?

Tags: mysql

Here's the MySQL I'm doing:

```
mysql> select "Le Café de la Mairie" as titre, "15 pl Mairie" as adresse1, id from ville where sound=soundex('FERTE SOUS JOUARRE') and cp='77260';
+-----------------------+--------------+-----+
| titre                 | adresse1     | id  |
+-----------------------+--------------+-----+
| Le Café de la Mairie  | 15 pl Mairie | 447 |
+-----------------------+--------------+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select "Le Café de la Mairie" as titre, "15 pl Mairie" as adresse1, id from ville where sound=soundex('FERTE SOUS JOUARRE') and cp='77261';
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Here's what I want:

```
mysql> select "Le Café de la Mairie" as titre, "15 pl Mairie" as adresse1, id from ville where sound=soundex('FERTE SOUS JOUARRE') and cp='77260';
+-----------------------+--------------+-----+
| titre                 | adresse1     | id  |
+-----------------------+--------------+-----+
| Le Café de la Mairie  | 15 pl Mairie | 447 |
+-----------------------+--------------+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> **(same query but dont find a record)**;
+--------------+------------+------+
| titre        | adresse1   | id   |
+--------------+------------+------+
| NULL         | NULL       | NULL |
+--------------+------------+------+

mysql>
```

Of course, I've already google & search stackoverflow.

Comment: can you use case statement or coalesce?

Comment: I just want it to work on 5.0.51a **`;)`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    t.*
FROM 
    (SELECT 1) AS dummy
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT ... your select here) AS t
      ON TRUE ;
```

So, to stick with the question:

```
SELECT
    t.*
FROM 
    (SELECT 1) AS dummy
LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT
        "Le Café de la Mairie" as titre,
        "15 pl Mairie" as adresse1,
        id
      FROM ville
      WHERE sound=soundex('FERTE SOUS JOUARRE')
      AND cp='77261') AS t
ON TRUE;
```

Comment: Hi, to stick with the sample in my question, I'm just changing "77260" to "77261" to make sur no records will be found. So if I put my query in your 'style', this would give: `SELECT t.* FROM dual LEFT JOIN (select "Le Café de la Mairie" as titre, "15 pl Mairie" as adresse1, id from ville where (sound=soundex('FERTE SOUS JOUARRE') and cp='77261') AS t ON TRUE;`

Comment: But this gives me an error: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN (select "Le Café de la Mairie" as titre, "15 pl Mairie" as adresse1, ' at line 1
`

Comment: Or rather, you have one more. Try this: `SELECT t.* FROM dual LEFT JOIN (select "Le Café de la Mairie" as titre, "15 pl Mairie" as adresse1, id from ville where sound=soundex('FERTE SOUS JOUARRE') and cp='77261') AS t ON TRUE;`

Comment: `mysql> SELECT t.* FROM dual LEFT JOIN (select "Le Café de la Mairie" as titre, "15 pl Mairie" as adresse1, id from ville where sound=soundex('FERTE SOUS JOUARRE') and cp='77261') AS t ON TRUE;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN (select "Le Café de la Mairie" as titre, "15 pl Mairie" as adresse1, ' at line 1
mysql>
`

Comment: Ohh I forgot: `MySQL Server version: 5.0.51a-24+lenny5 (Debian)`

Comment: My bad, `dual` does not work with `LEFT JOIN`, it appears. try the updated answer.

Comment: Great!! I've updated your answer with the solution that works, to stick with my question.